# Pass Event From .NET Web Application to .NET C# Standalone Application

Tags: c#, rest, events, asynchronous, delegates

Looking to create a web application that will modify a value in a database.   When this occurs, I need a C# standalone application to recoginize this occurred and pull the value that was modified.

When the web app updates the DB, can I fire an event to the standalone app so that it can call a stored proc and pull in the new value?   What is the most efficient approach to accomplish this task?

Comment: Look at Signalr.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your standalone app to a WCF service then call the service (server-side) when the form that does your database update is posted.

If you don't want to convert your standalone app (or can't), a quick hack that would still use WCF would be a simple one-line WCF app that uses System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() to invoke your standalone app.  Again, just invoke the service from your server-side logic after you've processed your database update.

I mention WCF as a solution because you're obviously already hosting your solution on IIS, that's exactly where you'd host your WCF app, and it's so darned simple to make WCF service calls from server-side code in .Net web apps.